# Need to add header and trailer record in a csv file - Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to azure data factory and need to implement below logic using Azure Data Factory where we are transferring a csv file from source to destination with some transformation in the file.

Input file contains below data :

```
111|101|2019-02-04 21:04:57

222|202|2019-02-04 21:33:54

333|202|2019-02-04 20:23:55
```

Expected Output :

```
H|TestFile|currentDateTime------------ Need to add this header record. H and TestFile would be static

111|101|2019-02-04 21:04:57

222|202|2019-02-04 21:33:54

333|202|2019-02-04 20:23:55

T|03-------------------------------------- T is static value. Need to add total number of records here.
```

Can someone please help with this

Comment: Can you use data flow?

Comment: Hi @rikta, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. Very Thanks! : )

Comment: Thank you so much Joseph... It is working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
After my series of tests, the final result I can get is as follows:
[image]
The structure overview is as follows:
[image]

1. I saved the header into a txt file.
   [image]
2. `source1` stores the source csv file, I set column name as `Column_1` at **Projection** tab.
   [image]
   The `source1` data preview is as follows:
   [image]
3. At **SurrogateKey1** activity, I key in `Row_No` as **Key column** and `1` as **Start value**.
   [image]
4. At `Window1` activity, select `Row_No` as Window column, then enter expression `max(Row_No)`.
   [image]
   `Window1` data preview is as follows, I can get the max value of the `Row_No`.
   [image]
5. Use `Pivot1` activity to switch from columns to rows, enter expression `concat('T|',toString(max(Row_No),'00'))` to get `T|03`.
   [image]
   `Pivot1` activity data preview is as follows:
   [image]
6. The settings of `source2` is the same as `source1`.
   [image]
7. At `DerivedColumn1`,
   set column name: `Column1` ,
   set expression: `concat(Column_1,'|',toString(currentTimestamp()))`.
   [image]
8. At `SurrogateKey2` activity, I key in `Row_No` as **Key column** and `2` as **Start value**.
   [image]
   `SurrogateKey2` activity data preview is as follows:
   [image]
9. At `Select2` activity, filter the column which we want and give this column an alias.
   [image]
   Data preview is as follows:
   [image]
10. `headers` stores the header info in a csv file. Set `Column_1` as column name.
    [image]
11. At `SurrogateKey3` activity, I key in `Row_No` as **Key column** and `1` as **Start value**.
    [image]
12. Union `SurrogateKey3` activity with `Select2` activity.
    [image]
    It will sort by `Row_No` column, so the title will be on the first line.
    [image]
13. Then we can only select what we need via `Select1` activity.
    [image]
    `Select1` activity data preview is as follows:
    [image]
14. Union `Pivot1` activity and `Select1` activity via `Union2` activity.
    [image]
    The `Union2` activity data preview is as follows:
    [image]
15. After run debug, final csv file is as follows:
    [image]

Comment: Hi Joseph,

Thanks alot for your response.

In the Header row, currentDateTime is not a static value and need to generate it with current datetime function. Any suggest how to proceed with it. Also we will get only 1 input file containing the actual data. 
I need to dynamically add header and trailer row.

Could you please suggest on this further...

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer.  Step7 will use  current datetime function to generate a new column. +10 from me.

Comment: This is working. Thank you so much Joseph :)